# how to filter information incoming from Deribit API

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, api

I am working on a project to simply receive information from the exchange and spit that out onto an excel spreadsheet. I have run into a road block where I am not sure how I would remove an unwanted list which is under the same variable name as a wanted list. for clarification:  [running_program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZLhU.png) the red pen indicates the list I want to remove, and the green being the useful information. Removing this will allow me to output the useful information into an excel spreadsheet to be viewed. This doesn't currently work due to the prior lists being used instead of the useful lists. How would I fix this? there are a few solutions such as removing said lists or using a different method to export the data to an excel spreadsheet. Any help would be appreciated.

I have established a connection with the API, then sorted the incoming data into lists using [start:end:step] to get all relevant information together, however this is what lead to sorting the [receiving message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZOcm.png) into lists too. So how would i remove this information to only use the useful information?

```
        every_mark_price = Response[4::4] #gets every mark price value from response
        mp_only = []

        for items in every_mark_price:
            sort = items.replace("\"mark_price\":","")#removes mark_price: from value
            mp_only.append(sort)
        df['Mark_Price'] = pd.Series(mp_only)#changes list into panda series and outputs into excel

        every_iv = Response[5::4]#gets every iv value from response
        iv_only = []
        
        for items in every_iv:
            sort = items.replace("\"iv\":","")#removes iv: from each value
            iv_only.append(sort)
        df['IV'] = pd.Series(iv_only)#changes list to panda series and outputs into excel

        every_instrument_name = Response[6::4]#gets every instrument name
        in_only = []
        
        for items in every_instrument_name:
            sort = items.replace("\"instrument_name\":","")
            sort_ = sort.replace("}","")#removes unnecessary char
            in_only.append(sort_)#adds it to new list
        df['Instrument_Name'] = pd.Series(in_only)#changes list into panda series and outputs into excel
```

Where I have used pandas to output into excel, it will only output the information highlighted by red in the image earlier(receiving message info) and to prevent this I need to somehow filter said info out or find a way to pass it. [excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sczrn.png)

Comment: have you tried putting the data into a dictionary or list and selecting the data that way?